# Row and Column Space Connection in Adjoint/Dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I wanted to clear my understanding of adjoints by relating it to the row and column space of a matrix. I recently spent time studying about Strang's 4 fundamantal subspaces(http://web.mit.edu/18.06/www/Essays/newpaper_ver3.pdf) which relate column space and null space.

I will refer to the adjoint map of a transformation(or matrix) $T$ as $T^T$ as we are only dealing with real spaces here.
Let $v$ be from $R^N$ and $w$ from $R^M$

The definition of adjoint says $\langle T v, w\rangle=\langle v, T^T w\rangle$

Here is the derivation $\langle T v, w\rangle=(Tv)^T \cdot w=v^TT^T \cdot w=v^T(T^Tw)=\langle  v,T^T w\rangle$

$Tv$ is a linear combination of the column space of $T$. We dot this with some $w$ already in that dimensional space. 
While $T^Tw$ is the linear combination of the row space which is dotted with our original $v$. Why do these yield the same result? I understand adjoints take a vector of one space to the appropriate space for the inner product but the operations are quite different. One is concerning column space and another row. I would like some intuition why they are equivalent.

Comment: " Why do these yield the same result?" I'm  not sure what you're asking. It _sounds_ as though you're asking why $Tv=T^Tw$, but that''s not so. What "two" yield the same result?

Comment: I meant the two sides of the adjoint definition, $\langle T v, w\rangle$ and $\langle v, T^T w\rangle$.

Answer (score 4):

Coming from a pure, functional analysis background, I always preferred to step away from matrices and dot products, and into linear maps and dual spaces (and inner products where applicable). The dot product can be thought of as a special type of inner product, but there's a further generalisation which I find helpful in terms of intuition. Bear with me, as there's a bit to brush over.

Consider a (real) normed linear space $V$. There's the notion of the (topological) dual $V^*$, which is the set of continuous linear functionals on $V$. What is a linear functional? It's a linear map from $V$ to the scalar field $\Bbb{R}$. That is, it is a function. The set of such functions forms a vector space (a vector subspace of all real-valued functions on $V$), and indeed comes with its own norm:
$$\|f\|_{V^*} = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} |f(x)|.$$
The continuity of $f \in V^*$ guarantees that this supremum is always finite.

Now, the dual $V^*$ interacts with $V$ in a very natural way. We can, in a sense, "multiply" a vector in $V$ with a vector in $V^*$ in the following way:
$$\langle v, f\rangle : = f(v).$$
Remember, $f \in V^*$ is a function of $V$. So, in this way, we obtain a scalar-valued product of $V$ and $V^*$. It's not difficult to see linearity here too:
\begin{align*}
\langle av_1 + v_2, f \rangle &= a\langle v_1, f \rangle + \langle v_2, f \rangle \\
\langle v , af_1 + f_2 \rangle &= a\langle v, f_1 \rangle + \langle v, f_2 \rangle.
\end{align*}
What else? Well, the definition of the norm of $f$ also yields the following inequality:
$$|\langle v, f \rangle| \le \|v\|_V \|f\|_{V^*}.$$
Look familiar? This looks a lot like Cauchy-Schwarz inequality!

This isn't an exhaustive list either. This scalar-valued between $V$ and $V^*$ shares a lot of properties with inner products. Indeed, in (complete) inner product spaces (e.g. $\Bbb{R}^n$), there is a very natural way of identifying $V^*$ with $V$ (the Riesz Representation Theorem), and in applying this identification to the $V^*$ argument, this scalar product *literally becomes* the inner product.

In many ways, I think it's a far more simple, intuitive beast than the inner product anyway. All it is is simple function evaluation, whereas the dot product is not quite so immediate.

---

So, what about $\Bbb{R}^n$? We can freely construct elements in the dual of $\Bbb{R}^n$ by deciding what happens to its standard basis. Let $E = (e_1, \ldots, e_n)$ be the standard basis, and for each $i$, consider the unique linear function $f_i$ that sends $e_i$ to $1$, and $e_j$ to $0$ for $j \neq i$. Then, $F = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ forms a basis (indeed the *dual basis* to $E$) of $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*$. Note that,
$$\langle e_i, f_j \rangle = \delta_{ij} = e_i \cdot e_j.$$
This suggests that we can identify $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*$ with $\Bbb{R}^n$, by turning a functional $f$ to its coordinate vector with respect to $F$, and this will turn the product between $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*$ into the standard dot product.

The convention is to denote vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$ by column vectors (really, these are matrices in $\Bbb{R}^{n \times 1}$), and elements of the dual, $(\Bbb{R}^n)^*$, by row vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{1 \times n}$. Then, the scalar product (which, again, is more or less the dot product) can be represented by matrix multiplication.

For example, $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \in \Bbb{R}^{1 \times 2}$ represents the linear functional $f(x, y) = x + 2y$. Evaluating it at $(1, -1) \in \Bbb{R}^2$ corresponds to the multiplication
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = -1 = f(1, -1),$$
which is, of course, the dot product between the vectors $(1, 2)$ and $(1, -1)$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$.

This is how I think about these things: column vectors are vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and row vectors are functionals on $\Bbb{R}^n$! Matrices in $\Bbb{R}^{m \times n}$, are really just a collection of $m$ row vectors (i.e. functionals), ready to accept vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and turn their scalar output into a (column) vector in $\Bbb{R}^m$.

---

So, with that in mind, let's tackle the adjoint. The adjoint is defined on a normed linear space the same way as it is on an inner product space, just with our alternate scalar product. Given $T : V \to W$, we define $T^*$ (leaving the domain and codomain blank for now) by:
$$\langle Tv, f \rangle = \langle v, T^*f\rangle.$$
What are the natural choices for domain and codomain here? Well, $Tv$ is a vector in $W$, making the left product the one derived from $W$. Thus, it looks like $f$ is going to have to be an element of $W^*$. On the right, $v \in V$ (necessary for $Tv$ to make sense), so the product must be derived from $V$. Thus, we can expect $T^*f \in V^*$. So, $T^* : W^* \to V^*$.

What does it do functionals in $W^*$? Well, if we write these products in terms of their definitions,
$$(T^*f)(v) = f(Tv) = (f \circ T)(v) \implies T^*f = f \circ T.$$
That is, the adjoint does something very simple and natural: it takes a functional on $W$, and turns it into a functional on $V$, by composing the map $T$ on the right! Again, these are natural operations given the objects at play here.

---

So, the hope is that this big info dump might help make it easier to see the answer to your question. An adjoint naturally operates on the dual space, i.e. a space of row vectors. Applying the adjoint to a dual/row vector $w$ "works" because $w$ is secretly a functional, and applying $T^*$ to it secretly composes $T$ with this functional. In that way, we get a functional/row vector which takes a vector $v$, applies $T$ to it, then applies $w$ to it. The row vector representing this total transformation is $T^*w$.

I hope that helps in some way. :-)

Comment: Let me spend some time on this and get back to you with questions

Comment: @RahulDeora Sure. If I have time tomorrow, I'll endeavour to answer some questions.

Comment: So when you say (∗)()=()=(∘)()  ---> $^*$=∘ and "That is, the adjoint does something very simple and natural: it takes a functional on  , and turns it into a functional on  , by composing the map   on the right"

Comment: @RahulDeora Yes?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\langle #1,#2\rangle}$

Theo Bendit's answer is much more interesting than  this one in terms of explaining wha's really going on mathematically. But if all you want to know is why $\ip{Tv}w=\ip v{T^Tw}$ in terms of matrices the answer is you can just work out both sides in terms of coordinates.

Say $T=(t_{j,k})$. Then the coordinates of $Tv$ are $(Tv)_j=\sum_kv_kt_{j,k}$, so $$\ip{Tv}w=\sum_{j,k}v_kw_jt_{j,k}.$$Similarly, since $(T^T)_{j,k}=t_{k,j}$, $$\ip v{T^T w}=\sum_{k,j}w_jv_kt_{j,k}.$$

Comment: Yes it will take time for me to go through his reasoning. I know how it works out but I wanted to know what happens in terms of column and row spaces if you could answer from that standpoint

Comment: Sorry, I don't see an explanation for $<Tv,w>-<v,T^Tw>$ in terms of column spaces and row spaces.